# jquery mobile table not fully hiding columns

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm new to jquery mobile, converting an app that I did for desktop.

Here's the versions I'm using:

jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css

jquery-1.11.3.js

jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js

I am using a single-page template.

Three pages, two of which have a table.

Tables defined as:

```
data-role="table" id="PortConfig_Table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive"
```

I'm using test data to make sure all works well.

Both tables have `th` elements set with priorities:

```
class="col-Dir" data-priority="3"
```

The HTML page just loads the header.

The first table implemented, I had script to load the table dynamically based on a "page" event.

I initially used `pageinit` but found that when I used the "columns" button that comes with the `columntoggle` table, only the header associated with the hidden column would disappear, the data cells in the column were still visible.

I surmised that JQM was probably assigning an attribute (or something) to the cells and I was populating the cells after JQM completed it's work.

I found if I triggered the data load on "page" event `pagebeforecreate`, the table worked as expected with header and data cells being hidden.

My second table uses multiple AJAX calls to acquire the table data.  The AJAX operations are triggered by the same page event - `pagebeforecreate`.

Table is fully populated - but the issue with only the column header being hidden when user requested column hide, or screen size shrinking to the point where JQM starts to hide columns based on priority rears it's ugly head again.

My question is ... how to dynamically load table contents and have the column hiding function hide the complete column - not just the column header.

Answer (score 0):

I added a table refresh after all my data was loaded and it solved the issue.